# Opacity css style doesn't work in ironPDF header

Tags: html, css, ironpdf

I generate an PDF with IronPDF and want to apply opacity on header. If I place my HTML string with opacity in document it's ok opacity work but when I place the same string with opacity in header, header doesn't show anymore like opacity = 0.

```
<div style='opacity: 0.1'> // work like opacity = 0 in header but work in document
<div style='opacity: 0.9'> // work like opacity = 0 in header but work in document
<div style='opacity: 0'> // work 
<div style='opacity: 1'> // work
```

Comment: Most HTML to PDF compilers can only use very basic CSS styling. According to IronPDF's documentation you can change the Opacity, but only for specific containers. See: https://ironpdf.com/c%23-pdf-documentation/html/F_IronPdf_HtmlStamp_Opacity.htm

Comment: In documentation it says opacity 0 is invisible and 100 is fully opaque. But for me when I set opacity to 1 or higher container is opaque and 0 to 0.9 container is invisible in header. If I set opacity in the document ironPDF understand the value between 0 and 1 but not for header and if header want  value between 0 and 100 it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting the opacity to `.9` in stead of `0.9`?

Comment: I tried and it work well in document but in header it's invisible

Comment: If you changed your opacities from `0.X` to `.X` it might be a bug in IronPDF's module. I would advise contacting them to check if it's a known bug.

Comment: I created a ticket I will update this post when I had more information about this.

Comment: Great! Because I'm curious if the module simply lacks functionality or you've stumbled upon a bug.